# Can anyone identify this SMD?

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount, laptop, motherboard

I can't get any readings with my multimeter (it's probably blown up), and the board doesn't have any schematics. I've been searching the net for hours and can't find anything about it.

[image]

It's the white one with the CL2 above it. This photo is for reference only, on my board that component doesn't even have a description or symbol.

Comment: I’m not sure what it is due to the blurry photo, but it doesn’t look like a chip. it’s likely a capacitor, resistor or inductor, perhaps a resonator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting things into context, the circuit in the picture is about Ethernet interface.

The component CL2 has a connection to Ethernet socket metal shell. Thus it must be the common mode capacitor between local groud and Ethernet ground.

Such a capacitor would typically be rated for maybe 1 to 2 kV and about 1 nF. The need for high voltage explains why the capacitor does not look like a standard SMD capacitor.

So, unless your multimeter can measure capacitors of roughly 1 nF in value, you won't get a reading. It might be blown but it would not prevent the device from working, it is an indication that if the capacitor is blown, there may have been a lightning strike and a lot more of the Ethernet interface has blown too.

Comment: The marking would indicates 101, 100pF if its a capacitor. The package would be 1808 which would be consistent with 2kV.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an SMT (one-time) fuse, but I don't find the markings very useful. It's possible there are markings on the sides. Bel fuse photo from Digikey:

[image]

Comment: I also think it looks like a fuse.

Comment: If you put things into context, do you usually see a fuse being connected to Ethernet connector metal shell, or a high voltage capacitor?

Comment: @Justme You could be right. The CL2 might be relevant. TBH, I didn't assume that was an Ethernet connector but it's definitely the shell.

Comment: JLAN sounds like Ethernet